# Why I get '401 unauthorized' when I open deployed app on Azure using docker compose?

Tags: azure, docker-compose

I want to deploy my full stack app to azure using docker-compose. Here is how it looks.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    networks:
      - application
  backend:
    image: dockerhubusername/backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - application
  frontend:
    image: dockerhubusername/frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - application

networks:
  application:
    name: application
    driver: bridge
```

When I run docker-compose up locally, I get app running. Frontend opens on localhost:80 as it should. But on azure as I open link to my app I get 'unauthorized' '401' 'Full authentication is required to access this resource'. I am new to cloud and I have no idea what the problem could be.

I made a new resource group and new web app resource. Also I choose deploy with docker-compose and I uploaded that file. I got notification deployment succeeded.